# Undefined big omega

Tags: big-o

I have

> n^3/100 -100n^2 -100n +3

and I need to find big theta. Is it possible to have an undefined lower bound? For the lower bound, no matter what value of n I use I never get a positive value of c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we try to find a **positive** constant `c` such that

```
(1/100)n^3 - 100n^2 - 100n + 3 >= cn^3
```

we will fail because for small values of `n` the left hand side is negative (e.g. `n=1`).

**But we do not need that!** We need the inequality to hold when `n` is above some threshold `n0`. So, let's keep that in mind while working to simplify our expression.

```
(1/100 - c)n^3 - 100n^2 - 100n + 3 >= 0     ; group by degree!
```

iff

```
(1/100 - c)n^3 >= 100n^2 + 100n - 3
```

if

```
(1/100 - c)n^3 >= 100n^2 + 100n             ; easy but effective
```

if

```
(1/100 - c)n^3 >= 100n^2 + 100n^2           ; key simplification!
                = 200n^2
```

iff

```
(1/100 - c)n >= 200
```

iff

```
((1 - c)/100)n >= 200
```

iff

```
n >= 20000/(1 - c)
```

and we can take `c = 1/2` and `n0 = 40000`.